# OData v4 Web API support for Composite Keys

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2, composite-key

I am building an OData Web Service using WebAPI and OData v4.

I was able to get the service to support composite keys through overriding the SelectAction method of the EntityRoutingConvention. However, in previous version of OData this was not needed. I personally believe it’s pretty messy and I feel like I am reinventing the wheel.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 5):

Use attribute routing.

An example:

*Model:*

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller method for identifying the entity using composite keys:*

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("Products(ID={key1},Name={key2})")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int key1, [FromODataUri] string key2)
{
    // You business logic for retrieving the entity from your storage using the two keys and return
}
```

*Request sample:*

```
GET http://host/service/Products(ID=1,Name='Car')
```

No need to override routing convention.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

does this also support for navigation properties?

`[ODataRoute("Products(ID={key1},Name={key2})/NavigationProperty")]`

Comment: @FrancescoFerraioli Yes it does.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the prefix "key" out of the box:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int keyID, [FromODataUri] string keyName)
{
    // You business logic for retrieving the entity from your storage using the two keys and return
}
```

I just checked with Microsoft.AspNet.OData v7.0.1

You can find it their source https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/samples/AspNetCoreODataSample.Web/Controllers/PeopleController.cs

Comment: This worked for me, but do you have documentation to back it up? Would be a good idea adding it to your answer.

Comment: Does not work with Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.4.

Comment: Doesn't work because of builder.EnableLowerCamelCase(). See [Issue 391](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/391)